# Are badges ever taken away?

Tags: discussion, badges

I was given an `enlightened` badge for a recent answer, because I was first to answer, it was accepted, and I earned 10 upvotes (woohoo!).

The OP received another answer (which was certainly better than mine) and they unaccepted my answer in favour of the other answer (no hard feelings :) ).

So, my question is: will my `enlightened` badge be taken from me?

Comment: The answer is here is "Maybe?" See [How do “badges” work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17853/168244)

Comment: @Werner nice link, thanks :) Adapting their example, I may not loose this badge, but might not gain a new one the next time I earn it

Comment: Badges?  You don't need no stinkin' badges (apologies to *Treasure of the Sierra Madre*)

Answer (score 11):

Tag badges disappear when you no longer meet the criteria. All other badges stay by default, no matter what you do. The only way to lose them is for an SE employee to recalculate your badges, and you have to do some large-scale sockpuppeting for them to bother with this.

Comment: My personal experience corroborates your claim. I once deleted one of my own post with score 3 and was awarded the Disciplined bronze badge. Within seconds, I had a change of heart and undeleted my answer, but my Disciplined badge remained. The next time I deleted one of my own post with score 3 or more, I was **not** awarded any Disciplined badge