# critic badge for a mistaken downvote

Tags: bug

I mistakenly downvoted a question and immediately upvoted instead - my original intent. But I've still got the critic badge I haven't earned. Not a big deal, not real bug despite the tag, but maybe it should go away.

Related: [Are badges ever taken away?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2820/are-badges-ever-taken-away)

Comment: I think this is pretty much covered in this question in meta.so: [Is the Critic badge awarded prematurely?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2137). The issue has been declared [tag:status-by-design].

Comment: Also see [Hunting for the Critic badge](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1739/5764).